# Pulling Data From Sharepoint List with Infopath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-rules

I am trying to get an InfoPath 2013 form to interact with a SharePoint list which has 6 columns currently:

```
ID   upc   name   cost   price
```

I am working on a basic InfoPath form with the following intention:

- The user types in a number in the "upc" field
- The "name" "cost" and "price" fields are populated with the information associated with the "upc" on my Sharepoint list.

I've been looking everywhere for a solution that works and nothing is working out.  This is what I've done, and from what I've read *should* work:

- Started new InfoPath form
- Went to the Data tab and  added a data connection "From SharePoint List" - the list name is "simpletest" - and selected the fields I'd be using
- Added two textbox fields to the form (field1 and field2)
- Created a rule on field2
      on the condition that "field1" "is equal to" "upc" (selected from the datafields portion of the "simpletest" connection)
      to perform an action "set a field's value" "field2" = "price" (selected from the datafields portion of the "simpletest" connection)

From what I can tell, this is correct.  But it doesn't work.  Does anyone see the holes in my methodology here?  It seems pretty straightforward, so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this right now, but I think you are somewhat close.

You could try to create a DropDown. ListBox choices and get choices from an external data source. Data Source -> your source list.

Now you probably don't want a drop down for every `upc`, so hide the DropDown and create your rules to work with the DropDown instead of directly to external data.

It might work, I am not sure.

The best solution would be to create a custom form in SharePoint designer, and use SPServices [SPServices.SPAutocomplete](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPAutocomplete). However, you will need to get familiar with JavaScript/jQuery.

InfoPath is good for making quick good looking forms, but feels a little like trying to fit a square peg in a round hole in more dynamic situations.